# How to create a remote amazon shopping cart using bottlenose

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, bottlenose

I'm using [bottlenose](https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose) for a program in Python that involves creating a shopping cart. The [README](https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose) isn't clear as to the parameters for the `CartCreate` method. After looking through the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CartCreate.html), it seems as if my call should look like this:

```
amazon.CartCreate(item.1.ASIN = item_id, item.1.Quantity = "1")
```

But the `.1`. is invalid syntax. How am I supposed to call this method?

Comment: Do you get a syntax error if you run It?

Comment: @roganjosh yes I get a syntax error specifically pointing to the period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, and apologies for not including an example for this in the documentation.

Just use a keyword argument to provide the values as a dictionary, like so:

```
params = {
    'Item.1.ASIN': item_id,
    'Item.1.Quantity': "1"
}

amazon.CartCreate(**params)
```